# 389DS Access.log parsing - turning LDAP request type into an audit event

Tags: ldap, audit, 389-ds

Has anyone authored code to parse a 389 Directory Server's access.log file with an aim of generating audit events based around the LDAP request type. Bascially, take the log sequence

```
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 fd=608 slot=608 connection from 207.1.153.51 to 192.18.122.139
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=0 BIND dn="cn=Directory Manager" method=128 version=3
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 filter="(uid=bjensen)"
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=1000 notes=U
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=2 UNBIND
[21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700] conn=11 op=2 fd=608 closed - U1
```

And turn this into an audit event with

a date/time (21/Apr/2007:11:39:51 -0700), a client location (207.1.153.51), server location (192.18.122.139), a user (cn=Directory Manager), an event (SRCH) and event metadata of (query - base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 filter="(uid=bjensen)", result set size - 1, timetaken = 1000 sec, etc)

The logconv.pl script seems to do all sorts of analysis, but no event representation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar use case to yours, but couldn't find anything that already existed.  I then came across [this 389ds page](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/design/audit-events.html) which describes an outline of what a script like this would produce.  The proposed solution was to include this functionality in future versions of logconv.pl.

For the time being, I ended up [writing a simple program](https://github.com/aidan-/ldap-access-parser) that follows this design.  I've been using it in production on a number of 389ds servers outputting the JSON results to an ELK stack using log-courier.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Aidan, that is exactly what I was after .. after my original post here I ended up writing the specification you found on 389ds.

Comment: Great to hear! I'll be updating the repo shortly with some pre-compiled binaries and fix up some of the documentation.